# Is it possible to use a custom work item type on the kanban board in azure devops?

Tags: azure-devops

My organization uses an inherited process based off of the Agile process.  However I created a custom work item type called `Product Backlog Item` because I liked this naming convention from the Scrum template and I use it for different purposes than User Stories.  Is there a way to use these on the `Boards` part of DevOps?

These are the only options, and I didn't see anywhere to add custom work item types to this section. [image: stories-features-epics]

In the settings this is all that I see as well.

[image: board-settings]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add your custom work items in process. Here are the steps:

1. Create a new work item type.
2. Add top level portfolio backlog.
   [image]
3. Select your custom work item type and set it as default.
   [image]
4. Select Product Backlog Item in Boards settings.

[image]

5. You can use Product Backlog Item on the Boards now.

[image]

Another way is edit Requirement backlog. You can change the name and select default work item type here.
[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!  Thank you!  I'm not sure how I overlooked this so many times.  It seems that editing the "Requirement backlog" however only allows you to create a new work item type there.  It wont let you use the custom one that you've already created.  The first option, however, should work fine for my purposes.

Comment: @abaga129  I am glad to know that it is useful to you. You could accept it as answer like [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).